# How to execute an Action without assigning it to JButton?

Tags: java

I have a list of Actions (I got them form HTMLEditorKit), and I want to execute them simply from the code, not from gui. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `actionPerformed` method on the action. You might have to create a `ActionEvent` though, but if you are lucky the implementation does not use it.